# How can I combine similar configuration info of server blocks in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I currently have 3 nginx configuration files for 2 server blocks in the standard file paths:

1. `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/one.website.com`
3. `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/two.website.com`

The `nginx.conf` includes all files in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` which have symlinks to the two websites in `sites-available` folder.

Both websites serve PHP files and the only difference between the two config files are

```
server_name
access_log
error_log
root
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=...
```

What is the best practice to consolidate the two website config files?

Here is the full config on one of them (note that setting the PHP `error_log` value is related to the nginx `error_log`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name one.website.com;
    access_log /usr/local/var/log/one.website.com-access.log;
    error_log  /usr/local/var/log/one.website.com-error.log;
    root /Users/hobbes3/Scripts/Neadwerx/one.website.com;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Disable favicon.ico logging
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Enable permalink structures
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite . /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; # 9000 for xdebug
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/usr/local/var/log/one.website.com-error.log";
    }

    # Disable static content logging and set cache time to max
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|html|htm|txt)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

    # Deny access to htaccess and htpasswd files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    #location ~ /\. {
    #    access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx's official line on this is *no, we like our configurations unwieldy and full of redundancies*; mainly because it's faster and their focus is on speed. They recommend using either:

- includes in each of your files under sites-configured that point to a common configuration file. Your distro probably didn't account for this when they created their folder structure, so you'll likely have to create something yourself.
- external configuration generation mechanism like a set of `sed` or `make` scripts to generate the configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to hear from the developer's point of view.